# SQL using SELECT to only choose one of several possible rows

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code so far:

```
DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.BirthdayMonth, @start_date)          as birthday_month,
Present.typeOfPresent                                           as birthday_present
DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.ChristmasMonth, @start_date)         as christmas_month,
Present.typeOfPresent                                           as christmas_present
```

The Present table contains 12 different months (in DATEADD format), with each month corresponding to a different present to get someone.

I want birthday_present from the Present table to correspond to the present listed in the month birthday_month, and similarly for christmas_present. In pseudocode, something like:

```
DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.BirthdayMonth, @start_date)          as birthday_month,
Present.typeOfPresent WHERE Present.month=DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.BirthdayMonth, @start_date)                                        as birthday_present
DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.ChristmasMonth, @start_date)         as christmas_month,
Present.typeOfPresent WHERE Present.month=DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.ChristmasMonth, @start_date)                                           as christmas_present
```

Comment: i always get jipped in December

Comment: Can't this be done with a join?

Answer (score 0):

Use two joins with the `Present` table

```
SELECT p1.month          as birthday_month,
        p1.typeOfPresent as birthday_present
        p2.month         as christmas_month,
        p2.typeOfPresent as christmas_present
FROM SpecialDays AS s
JOIN Present AS p1 ON p1.month = DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.BirthdayMonth, @start_date) 
JOIN Present AS p2 ON p2.month = DATEADD(month, SpecialDays.ChristmasMonth, @start_date)
```